# Add removed select options

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a function I created that removes some options from a select menu based on a value passed from another select. I want to revert back to normal each time the function is called (add all the original options back)

### HTML

```
<select id="Current-Tier" onchange="removetier();" class="form-control boosting-select">
        <option value="100">Bronze</option>
        <option value="200">Silver</option>
        <option value="300">Gold</option>
        <option value="400">Platinum</option>
        <option value="500">Diamond</option>
</select>

<select id="Desired-Tier" class="form-control boosting-select">
        <option value="100">Bronze</option>
        <option value="200">Silver</option>
        <option value="300">Gold</option>
        <option value="400">Platinum</option>
        <option value="500">Diamond</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
 function removetier(){

     var currentTierValue = document.getElementById("Current-Tier");
     var current = currentTierValue.options[currentTierValue.selectedIndex].value;

     var desiredDivisionValue = document.getElementById("Desired-Tier");
     for(var i=0;i<desiredDivisionValue.length;i++){
         if(desiredDivisionValue[i].value < current){
             desiredDivisionValue.remove(desiredDivisionValue[i]);

         }
     }

     Update_Desired_Rank_image();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered adding the [`hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) attribute rather than deleting them?

Then the next time you receive a request, you can go through the list programmatically and remove the `hidden` attribute from each option.

An example of the `hidden` label, BTW, is

```html
<select id="Desired-Tier" class="form-control boosting-select">
  <option value="100">Bronze</option>
  <option value="200">Silver</option>
  <option value="300">Gold</option>
  <option value="400">Platinum</option>
  <option value="500" hidden>Diamond</option>
</select>
```

If you run it you will see that Diamond is hidden. This way you always have access to all your options.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily iterate over the `select` input and either store the removed items in an array or leverage the `hidden` attribute on the `option` tag:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLwwmh82/2/

HTML

```
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="test1">Test1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test2</option>
        <option value="test3">Test3</option>
        <option value="test4">Test4</option>
        <option value="test5">Test5</option>
        <option value="test6">Test6</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btnRemove" onclick="remove()">Remove Half of Entries</button>
    <button id="btnReset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

JS

```
function reset() {
    var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    var options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].removeAttribute('hidden');
    }
}

function remove() {
    var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    select.value = "";
    var entries = select.querySelectorAll('option');
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
        // Wrap the below line in your logic to know what to delete/not to delete
        entries[i].setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: works fine but it doesnt refresh so i still see the hidden option selected but when i click on the select menu its not there

Comment: Just updated it. Try again and it should behave as expected.

Comment: am sorry but i dont understand anything from what you added

Comment: oh i see now its just showing a blank text selected instead of the one which  was there

Comment: i dont need a blank text i need the text one to be selected

Comment: Exactly, There's other ways to do it but that's the most basic.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to specify which one you want selected. You haven't mentioned any specifics on that in your question. Please remember to upvote on answers that help

Comment: what are the other ways? :)

Comment: Instead of reverting back to a blank value (the default Select...) option, you could just default it to the next option in line.

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: Your original question was for hiding elements in the drop down which i've answered in full for you. Now you are asking additional things. I will answer that if you accept as answer/upvote.